# Strange rendering issue using WPF within a WinForm

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, user-interface, user-controls

I'm displaying a WPF `UserControl` (which contains a `DataGrid` and another `UserControl` for paging) on a `WinForm` inside an `ElementHost`. when I display that form and it attempts to render it to the GUI I get the following error

```
UIElement.Measure(availableSize) cannot be called with NaN size
```

I have checked and none of the Size objects are null or have unexpected values.

What is confusing me is that if I display a `MessageBox` right before the call then the form renders perfectly. The same `UserControl` also renders perfectly on a different `WinForm` and works perfectly when testing on my Win8 pc but not on a Win7 server, any ideas would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How does 'availableSize' get set?  Where are you getting that value?  When you don't specify a size for something, like a width, and then get the value for width, you will have 'nan' returned.  So if you're doing something like

```
double availableSize = someControl.Width;
```

It is going to set availableSize to 'double.nan'.  Because it isn't really a value.  It isn't really set.  It is not null, but it hasn't been set to anything.  This way, the control can autosize to its container, given the right context.

Anyway, if `availableSize == nan` and you're trying to call:

`UIElement.Measure(availableSize)`  You will get that NaN exception that you are seeing.

Hope this clears it up for you.  You can just check to see if it is NaN before you use it.

```
if(availableSize != double.Nan)
{
   measurement = UIElement.Measure(availableSize);
}
```

Comment: availableSize is not my variable, it seems to be getting set internally in the renderer. I have found the solution though, some code was being called from the Load event which was affecting the DataGrid UI, I moved this to the Shown event and all is well. Thanks for your answer though!